# How do I view the tab completion function for a command in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, gnu-screen, tab-completion

I ultimately want to alias `screen -r`.

I mostly want to do this because that command has an awesome tab completion feature that shows me the current GNU screen sessions. I want that power with the alias.

This led me to ask a more general question. How would I view the tab completion function for the command `screen -r` or further, any command?

Comment: `help complete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so there are three different things going on in the question:

1) To look up the bash completion function of a command `complete -p <command>` does the trick. In this case `complete -p screen` yields `complete -o default -F _screen screen`

2) Bash completion will take arguments. In the case of `screen -r`, the `screen` bash completion function gets called with `-r` as an argument. You may then auto-complete conditionally from there.

3) On Ubuntu, `/etc/bash_completion.d/screen` has the screen completion function defined.

So the way I aliased `screen -r` and kept the completion function was as follows.

`.bashrc:`

```
alias scr="screen -r"
function _complete_scr() {
    local does_screen_exist=$(type -t _screen_sessions)
    local cur=$2 # Needed by _screen_sessions
    if [[ "function" = "${does_screen_exist}" ]]; then
        _screen_sessions "Detached"
    fi
}
export -f _complete_scr
complete -F _complete_scr -o default scr
```